# How to slide images by clicking arrows bullets and auto slide images by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want bullets move when i clicked arrow,i tried to think how to code it but my knowledge and experience is still not enough so i really need help from people.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mainTopics").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#sub-topics").toggle();
    });

    $("html").on('click', function () {
        if ($("#sub-topics").is(':visible')) {
            $("#sub-topics").toggle();
        }
    });
});

var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
var arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#arrow-left');
var arrowRight = document.querySelector('#arrow-right');
var arrowSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');
var sliderBullets = document.querySelectorAll('.bullets');
var current = 0;

//reset slideimages
function resetSlide() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

//slide left
function slideLeft() {
    resetSlide();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
    current--;
}

//slide right
function slideRight() {
    resetSlide();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
    current++;
}

//arrow left
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (current === 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideLeft();
});

//arrow right
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
        current = -1;
    }
    slideRight();
});

//start to slideimages
function startSlide() {
    resetSlide();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
}

//called startslide function
startSlide();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}

/*main-menu*/
#main-menu {
    position: relative;
}

#main-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}

/*sub-topics*/
#sub-topics {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#sub-topics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#sub-topics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}

/*columns*/
#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

/*hover underline*/
#main-menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*slideshow*/
#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#slide1 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/mV3TR7/1.jpg);
}

#slide2 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/bSCBeS/2.jpg);
}

#slide3 {
    background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/kgG9Yn/3.jpg);
}

.slide {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 800px 400px;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.slide-contain {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    text-align: center;
}

.slide-contain span {
    color: white;
}

/*arrow*/
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 200px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.arrow:hover {
    background-color: #e0dede;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/*arrow-left*/
#arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 30px 40px 30px 0px;
    border-color: transparent gray transparent transparent;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 300px;
}

/*arrow-right*/
#arrow-right {
    border-width: 30px 0px 30px 40px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent gray;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 300px;
}

/*bullets*/
#slidebullet {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bullets {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .bullets:hover {
    background-color: #e0dede;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <nav>
        <div id="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" id="mainTopics">Topics</a>
                    <div id="sub-topics">
                        <div id="column1" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="slideshow">

        <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>

        <div id="slide1" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image One</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide2" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Two</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slide3" class="slide">
            <div class="slide-contain">
                <span>Image Three</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidebullet">
            <div id="bullet1" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet2" class="bullets"></div>
            <div id="bullet3" class="bullets"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the code that i have learned from website asked people and youtube.
My website now the arrows work fine can change to other slides,but the bullets are not moving the same time like arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal can be reached by adding the following javascript code to your js file:

```
for (var i=0 ;i<sliderBullets.length;i++)
{
    bullet=sliderBullets[i];
    bullet.addEventListener("click",function(){

    var i=this.id;
    i=i.replace("bullet","");
    current=parseInt(i)-1;
    resetSlide();
    sliderImages[current].style.display = 'block';


  });
}
```

Comment: Can this code make it shorter ? like using for or loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one , its very easy .

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h